# Convert from Android.Media.Image to Android.Graphics.Bitmap (possibily with Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, android-bitmap, android-image

I have a Android.Media.Image frame acquired from Camera2 API Preview (in a Xamarin app), that I want to process.
The image format is YUV_420_888.

In a previous iteration I was able to get a Android.Graphics.Bitmap from the CameraPreview (but not anymore), and with that bitmap I was able to:

- crop it
- convert it to JPEG, save it or send it to server
- convert it to a Mat to process with Emgu in real time

I searched for how to convert from Android.Media.Image to Android.Graphics.Bitmap thinking it was going to be quite straightforward, but it's not.
I found mostly java code that I tried to convert to C# Xamarin but without success.

First step is supposed to be to convert to a YuvImage (found 2 different versions, hence the comments):

```
private static byte[] YUV_420_888toNV21(Android.Media.Image image)
        {
            byte[] nv21;
            ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
            ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.GetPlanes()[1].Buffer;
            ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.GetPlanes()[2].Buffer;

            int ySize = yBuffer.Remaining();
            int uSize = uBuffer.Remaining();
            int vSize = vBuffer.Remaining();

            nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];

            //yBuffer.Get(nv21, 0, ySize);
            //vBuffer.Get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
            //uBuffer.Get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

            yBuffer.Get(nv21, 0, ySize);
            uBuffer.Get(nv21, ySize, uSize);
            vBuffer.Get(nv21, ySize + uSize, vSize);
            
            return nv21;
        }
```

And then the saving:

```
var bbitmap = YUV_420_888toNV21(image);
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(bbitmap, ImageFormatType.Nv21, image.Width, image.Height, null);
var ms = new MemoryStream();
yuv.CompressToJpeg(new Android.Graphics.Rect(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), 100, ms);
File.WriteAllBytes("/sdcard/Download/testFrame.jpg", ms.ToArray());
```

But this is the result:

[image]

This was just a test to actually save and check the captured frame, because at the end of this I still don't have a Bitmap (even if it was working).

In cas of real time processing, I don't want/need the JPG conversion becaus it would only slow down everything.
I'd like to convert the Image to a Bitmap, crop it and feed it to Emgu as a Mat.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: What do you import for `ImageFormatType.Nv21`?